# Truffle installed but not working properly

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle, consensys-truffle

I'm using node version 12.20.2 and npm version 6.14.11 and installed truffle with cmd as administrator, the truffle framework version 5.5.12 has been installed but when I run any command in the vs code, it pops up with an error

```
PS E:\Testing (roughf work)> truffle version
truffle : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on 
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at      
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ truffle version
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS E:\Testing (roughf work)> truffle init
truffle : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on 
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at      
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ truffle init
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I don't know what to do with this

Comment: Please explain what you have done so far and what command you executed?

Answer (score 3):

On the truffle quickstart, it states [to use nvm](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/quickstart/), as permission errors like this will occur. However, to solve this error, you can also use this powershell command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`